Does a skylight provide indirect sunlight to plants?
My house has a skylight that works like this: there’s a clear acrylic dome on the roof, which lets light in. The light travels down a conduit lined with aluminum foil and enters the ceiling of my room.  The room is quite bright during the day, so there is a fair bit of light getting through.
This is the only source of ‘sunlight’ in the room. Will this be enough indirect light for a house plant?

what kind of house plant?  How tall will it be, which direction does the skylight face and is the direction unobstructed by trees or buildings?

Would you be able to provide a few pictures of the skylight and the room?

It is difficult to answer. You just measured with eyes, so with some errors: inside your eyes adapt very quickly, so it is difficult to know if it is brighter than a forest or under single trees. (really: it is difficult to judge, also for expert, so photographer had a lightmeter). Also we may block UV and IR (one to keep stuffs not braking, the other as overheating protection), which we do not see with eyes. And some plants like IR (infra-red).

It might be useful to use a cellphone  Light Meter App to work out how much light you are receiving.    The light should be sufficient for indoor plants but won't be great for plants normally found outdoors.  Our eyes fool us when it comes to light levels (our pupils expand without us being aware of it - Outdoor light levels are typically between 10 and 100 times higher then indoor areas)

You could grow shade plants, not many flowers. Hold your hand out to create a shadow. If you cannot produce one, you have low light (high shade). Only flowering plant I know for that is peace plant, spathiphyllum. Sits in a saucer of water and makes a poor-man's calla lily, sorta.

@davidgo exactly. Without further detail the question is not answerable. Fiber optics are so efficient that with proper lenses one could melt rocks on a winter day. Input and output area and geographic longitude will probably be informative but not as much as a direct measurement.

Are you asking for a lux measurement or something Vorac?  If you’re asking for something objective be specific.  I do not have a sunlight that can melt rocks in my home, in case that wasn’t clear enough for you in my question.

Indeed, a skylight can give plants indirect sunlight, which is usually ideal for a variety of houseplants. Diffuse light that is reflected by the aluminum-lined conduit and passes through the acrylic dome lessens direct light. Many indoor plants flourish in the bright, indirect light produced by this arrangement. However, variables like the size of the skylight, the size of the space, and seasonal variations may affect the intensity. Keep an eye on your plants' growth and alter their position as necessary to make sure they are receiving enough light. Some plants, especially those with high light requirements, can still need extra lighting.
